# Nested iFrames, parent resize doesn't bubble up

Tags: iframe-resizer

I have the following structure:

```
0. Parent page
    1. iFrame rendered through ad delivery network
        2. iFrame displaying the advertisement
```

The ad is setup to resize the parent iFrame through the parentIFrame.size() method when a user interacts with the advertisement.  I have this part setup and working properly -- I can see the inline style attributes change on the Level 2 iframe.

Now, looking at the [demo](http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/example/) I can see that it's possible to have nested iFrames work together and have the sizing appropriately bubble through the nested levels.  I see that the middle level iFrame must be setup having both the contentWindow and the iFrameResize files.

Given the my Level 2 iframe does work and resize properly, I'm assuming the communication between Level 1 and Level 2 is working properly and my problem lies somewhere between Level 0 and Level 1.  I have set up a [simplified test case](http://cachicha.tv/utils/ads/rich-media/test.html) and deliberately have iFrameResize logging turned *off* within Level 2.

If you view the console, you'll notice something like the following when the ad renders:

```
[iFrameSizer][Host page] IFrame scrolling disabled for sas_i30430
[iFrameSizer][Host page][init] Sending msg to iframe (sas_i30430:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:offset:null:null:0)
[iFrameSizer][Host page][iFrame.onload] Sending msg to iframe (sas_i30430:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:offset:null:null:0)
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] HTML & body height set to "auto"
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Enable public methods
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Enable MutationObserver
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Trigger event lock on
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Sending message to host page (sas_i30430:250:300:init)
[iFrameSizer][Host page] Received: [iFrameSizer]sas_i30430:250:300:init
[iFrameSizer][Host page] Checking height is in range 0-Infinity
[iFrameSizer][Host page] Checking width is in range 0-Infinity
[iFrameSizer][Host page] Requesting animation frame
level 2. registering handler -- resizing to 250, 300
[iFrameSizer][Host page] IFrame (sas_i30430) height set to 250px
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLIFrameElement] attributes
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] No change in size detected
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Trigger event lock off
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] --
```

Then when you click on the ad, the following appears:

```
level 2. expand action -- resizing to 250, 482
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] Trigger event: mutationObserver: [object HTMLIFrameElement] attributes
[iFrameSizer][sas_i30430] No change in size detected
```

You can see that I'm logging events from Level 2 to help segment the logs.  The last part where the Level 2 iFrame is resized, but then the Level 1 iFrame observes no change in size is where I'm having the disconnect.

Level 0 has the following:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cachicha.tv/utils/ads/rich-media/assets/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('.adunit').find('iframe').iFrameResize({
            log: true,
            checkOrigin: false,
            autoResize: true,
            enablePublicMethods: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Level 1 has the following (this is strange, i know, but necessary with the ad network... and this part is working.  I'm providing it for completeness):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var scripts = [
        "http://cachicha.tv/utils/ads/rich-media/assets/js/iframeResizer.min.js",
        "http://cachicha.tv/utils/ads/rich-media/assets/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"
    ];

    var jQueryScriptLoaded = function() {
        // load the other scripts after jquery
        for (var i = scripts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var element = document.createElement("script");
            element.onload = function() {
                scriptsLoaded();
            };
            element.src = scripts[i];
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(element);
        };
    };

    var scriptsLoaded = function() {
        // fire jquery onces all scripts are loaded in the right order
        jQuery(function($) {
            $('iframe').prop('width', '').prop('height', "100%");

            $('iframe').iFrameResize({
                // log                     : true,                  // Enable console logging
                enablePublicMethods     : true,                  // Enable methods within iFrame hosted page
                sizeHeight              : true,
                sizeWidth               : true,
                checkOrigin             : false,
                autoResize              : false,
            });
        });
    }

    // load jquery first.
    var jqueryScript = document.createElement('script');
    jqueryScript.onload = function() {
        jQueryScriptLoaded();
    };
    jqueryScript.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jqueryScript);

</script>
```

Level 2 has the contentWindow script and parentIFrame.size() calls.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you set the height of the inner iFrame to 100% in your jQuery.